# get radio button selected value of form in controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to **echo the radio buttons selected value by using document.write** **(only for as of now)..** So it's actually creating a problem with the code

JavaScript Code:

```
$scope.Next = function(){
    var queid = $scope.id1;
    var ans = $scope.radio;
    document.write(queid);
    document.write(ans);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form style="text-align:left;width:90%;margin-left:10px;" ng-controller="dropdownCtrl">
  <div class="tab" ng-repeat="e in disp">
    <p>{{e.question}}</p>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="id1"  ng-init="id1=e.id" name="id1" ng-value="{{e.id}}" />

<label class="container2">Option A : {{e.option_a}}
<input type="radio" checked="checked" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_a"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container2">Option B : {{e.option_b}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_b"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container2">Option C : {{e.option_c}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_c"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container2">Option D : {{e.option_d}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_d"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
  </div>

<div style="overflow:auto;">
<div style="float:right;">
<button type="button" ng-click="Next()" style="background:#acddde;color:black;border-radius:3px;border:none;width:80px;height:30px;">Next</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: whats the problem??

Comment: On click that NEXT button it's showing undefined.. asper the document.write... Basically it's unable to read the values (i think).

Comment: and also you in ng repeat everytime you are setting  value of id of each repeated element to only one variable id1

Comment: can you also add the content of disp array

Comment: the only change i made and it's also working that is i gave ng-repeat in form rather than giving in div.

Answer (score 0):

The only change made which is working that is to **put ng-repeat in form**... Because it also then includes the button. So we can take ng-repeat in the form or else take a div which covers the whole form content inside from the first input to the last button, and add ng-repeat to that div.

JavaScript Code:

```
$scope.Next = function(){
    var queid = $scope.id1;
    var ans = $scope.radio;
    document.write(queid);
    document.write(ans);
}
```

Html Code:

```
<form style="text-align:left;width:90%;margin-left:10px;" ng-controller="dropdownCtrl" class="tab" ng-repeat="e in disp">
    <p>{{e.question}}</p>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="id1"  ng-init="id1=e.id" name="id1" ng-value="{{e.id}}" />

<label class="container2">Option A : {{e.option_a}}
<input type="radio" checked="checked" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_a"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container2">Option B : {{e.option_b}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_b"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container2">Option C : {{e.option_c}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_c"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container2">Option D : {{e.option_d}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="radio" name="radio1" ng-value='"option_d"'>
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<div style="overflow:auto;">
<div style="float:right;">
<button type="button" ng-click="Next()" style="background:#acddde;color:black;border-radius:3px;border:none;width:80px;height:30px;">Next</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```